# Deleting object from the url

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to override delete action in my CategoryViewSet, the build in delete action taked the id of the category `DELETE ..category/1/`, but I want it to delete by the slug argument `DELETE ..category/movie/`. I can not figure out how can I withdraw slug field from the url (*args)

models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        verbose_name='Category Name'
    )

    slug = models.SlugField(
        unique=True,
        verbose_name='Slug Name',
        max_length=50
    )
```

serializers.py

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'slug')
```

views.py

```
class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            slug = args[0]
            delete_category = Category.objects.filter(slug=slug)
            self.perform_destroy(delete_category)
        except Http404:
            pass
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

urls.py

```
router_v1.register(
    r'categories',
    CategoryViewSet
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router_v1.urls))
]
```

Comment: Is delete the only action you want to lookup via the category slug?

Comment: @tomvanner yes, it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set non default `lookup_field`. Do it in your `serializers` and `views`.

serializers:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        ...
        lookup_field = 'slug'
```

views:

```
class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...
    lookup_field = 'slug'
```